# Can this storm door be repaired

Tags: metal, hardware

Update: Unfortunately Chamberdoor does not sell hinges even though it's pretty simple to replace them. They do sell the Z Bar but with shipping it's almost $100. These hinges were not sold at either the big orange box or the big green box. I ordered online and fortunately what I ordered I was able to make work. I bought a pin kit and the only issue was my hinge had some casting flash so the nylon pin wouldn't slide in. A 5/16 drill was the perfect size to remove it. None of these hinge kits or pin kits have an application or brand listed. Most of them do list dimensions so if you disassemble you should be able to get the right kit. If I were to do this again I would remove the door take out the hinge measure it and then order based on the measurements. [image: Old Hinge Parts][image: New Hinge Parts]

This door is starting to sag, when it closes it hits the other door near the top. It looks like the hinge has worn out. I was at the big box store and I didn't see any replacement hinges so I'm thinking the hinge is integral to the frame. Is there any way this can be fixed. If it was just the single door I wouldn't mind replacing it but not likely I can find this same door five years later.

[image: Hinge from outside]
[image: Top of door]
[image: Bottom of door]
[image: Entire door]
[image: Hinge from inside]

Comment: Are you sure it's not the screws holding the hinge to the door or the hinge to the door frame that is the problem?  That's what it looks like from here.

Comment: Have you tried opening the door and then whacking the hinge a bit to try and bend it into the frame a bit?

Comment: Not the screws, if you push on the door it will line up, you can see the play in the hinge. Once you pull on it to open it it sags again. I think Jack has a good idea as a last resort before replacing the door.

Comment: Have you pulled that hinge pin to see if it's worn? I've seen that happen, especially if it wasn't kept well lubricated. In which case just replace the pin. Also, have you contacted the manufacturer to see about a replacement hinge?

Comment: There's no easy access to the hinge pin. I'd have to remove the door to get access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No easy way to replace the hinge? Is much cheaper than replacing the entire door that will take the same steps to disassemble.
I would remove the door from the hinge then pull the frame then the hinge can be replaced it won’t be simple but hinges will be much cheaper than the entire door. Just take the hinge with you and match the size.
I have replaced aluminum hinges like these with steel ones I did paint the steel to match the door prior to installing this saved me a lot but did take a couple hours to complete.

Comment: I thought the hinges were part of the z-bar. If they can be replaced I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, but in my case, it's screen doors, so very lightweight in comparison to yours.  I may be wrong, but I don't think you can repair individual hinges on that type of door. I think you're going to be needing to replace the entire hinge rail on that side.  This component is also known as a Z-bar.  You should try to determine the manufacturer of your door, and then you can check with them to see if they sell replacement Z-bars for your door - they run anywhere from $30-$60, depending on size.  Here's a URL to an example replacement part for a brand that appears to be similar to your design: https://www.menards.com/main/doors-windows-millwork/door-window-hardware/storm-door-replacement-parts/survivor-80-aluminum-storm-door-hinge-side-z-bar/71922/p-1444423382755.htm  Good luck!